permutation in python return set of same data
as a beginner I wrote in python code that suppose to generate permutations, and it does not work.
In __run method I print value of self.data before appending it to self.result and in output I see different values but after algorithm completed and I print out returned self.result I see set of same  values [1,2,3,4] (what data was initialized with).
Can someone experienced tell me what wrong with this code ?
class Perm:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.result = []
    def __run(self, start_idx = 0):
        if (start_idx == len(self.data) - 1):
            print("# ", self.data)
            self.result.append(self.data)
        else:
            for i in range(start_idx, len(self.data) - 1):
                j = i + 1
                while j < len(self.data):
                    self.data[i], self.data[j] = self.data[j], self.data[i]
                    self.__run(start_idx + 1)
                    self.data[i], self.data[j] = self.data[j], self.data[i]
                    j += 1
    def __call__(self):
        self.__run()
        return self.result


data = [1,2,3,4]
perm = Perm(data)
res = perm()
print("+++++++++++++++++++++++")
for r in res: print(r)

thanks in advance guys

There really is no need to be using "name mangling" here with double underscores.

This is a good time to learn about the yield keyword

This is a great opportunity to learn to use a debugger.
